# Remote Desktop from Windows 8 cannot connect

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

In my home I have two computers, one running on Windows 7 and the other one is on Windows 8.
I am able to connect my office computer using the Windows 7 computer. But I am unable to connect using my Windows 8 computer.

I am able to setup the VPN, but I am unable to ping. I tried with disabling the firewall, but I am still unable to ping/use [Remote Desktop Connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#Remote_Desktop_Connection).

How can I solve it?

Comment: When you say 'Using the Windows 7 computer" are you talking about connecting to it (W7 is acting as the server, W8 is the client) or the other way around?   

Is the office computer running windows 7 or windows 8?   Is the office computer you mention either one of the aforementioned machines or is this a 3rd computer?   When you say office I am assuming you mean a computer at a remote location (at work perhaps?).   I am also going to assume that since you said "I am able to setup the VPN" you are referring to a computer at a remote location - but you really need to clarify if you want help.